# How to refernce view to itself

Tags: view

I am using Crystal Reports and I am trying to upload a view. I want the view to reference itself but I get this error message:
" View or function 'ProductionOrdreItemsFull' contains a self-reference. Views or functions cannot reference themselves directly or indirectly."

Does anyone have a clue how can I call a view from itself?

```
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
 UNION
 SELECT        T8.DocEntry, - 3, T9.Code, T8.PlannedQty * T9.Quantity, 
 T8.CompTotal * T9.Quantity, T10.ItemName, T10.QryGroup5
 FROM            dbo.ProductionOrdreItemsFull T8 INNER JOIN
                     ITT1 T9 ON T8.ItemCode = T9.Father INNER JOIN
                     OITM T10 ON T9.Code = T10.ItemCode
 WHERE        T8.LineNum = - 2
```

Answer (score 0):

A View definition can't refer to itself. But, you can achieve the same thing using Common Table Expressions (CTEs). See for example [this blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/simonince/2007/10/17/hierarchies-with-common-table-expressions/) about 'Hierarchies WITH Common Table Expressions'.

Crystal also has a special "Hierarchical Grouping" feature you can Google.